# Embed facebook video full width

Tags: html, css, facebook

I tried lot of solution without success.
How could I embed facebook video with full width ?

I use this code :

```
.videoWrapper{
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
/* 16:9 */
padding-top: 25px;
height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

and :

```
<div class="col-lg-12 videoWrapper px-0" style="border:1px solid #000;">
<iframe loading="lazy" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?height=314&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FTVcarcassonne%2Fvideos%2F1048478559377806%2F&amp;show_text=false&amp;width=560&amp;t=0&amp;autoplay=true" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" width="560" height="314" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
```

It works for YoutubeVideo but not for facebook video.
You could see the problem on https://dev.dibona.fr/tv/.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Facebook restricts the content _inside_ the iframe, to the width specified via the URL parameter. You can make the iframe itself wider, but the content will stay as it is. According to documentation, it should support a value `auto` for the width, but I am not sure how good that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded solution after 1 week !

```
<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2"></script>
   <div class="fb-video"
   data-href="http://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXX/videos/XXXXXX"
   data-width="auto"
   data-show-captions="false">
   </div>
```

Put "data-width" to auto like CBroe said.